# Crop image from the top

Tags: css

It's pretty easy to crop an image from the bottom, left or right by setting the `overflow: hidden` property of the container of the image.

```
<div class="img-container">
   <img class="img" src="/img.jpg" />
</div>

<style>
   .img-container {
       overflow: hidden;
       max-height: 700px;
   }

   .img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Is there any way to crop the image from the top? If the window is being resized and the image cannot fit into the height of the container anymore, the image should be cropped from the top instead of from the bottom.

Comment: try `position:absolute; bottom: 0;`

Comment: That works, thank you!

Comment: glad it helped!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to the div container (and a height).

Then add `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` to the image itself:

```css
.img-container {
       overflow: hidden;
      height: 100px;
       max-height: 300px;
       position: relative;
   }

.img {
     display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
   <img class="img" src="http://placekitten.com/400/500" />
</div>

<p>Full image below</p>
   <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/500" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is applying the image as a background and then positioning it the bottom of the container. Apply `background-size` to preserve aspect ratio:

```css
.img-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/400/500) no-repeat bottom;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container"></div>
```