# Cropping the top 10% of an image using CSS?

Tags: css, crop

How to crop the top of an image has already been described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092973/crop-image-from-the-top). However, I am trying to crop an image by a percentage when the image dimensions are not known ahead of time. *The container's resulting height should then be dependent on the size of the image.*

Using the following, I can crop the top of an image, but it requires manually specifying the amount of the image to show in pixels. Is there a way I can specify I want to crop the top 10% of the image without knowing the image size ahead of time?

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 370px;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="img" src="http://placekitten.com/400/500" />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want 90% of the image to show in a fixed-height container, with it's top 10% hidden? Or should the height of the container be unspecified?

Comment: @showdev, The height of the container should be unspecified (based on the image size). My final desired situation is to have the image be based on dimensions `max-height: 70vh; max-width: 100vw;`, but I left that out to keep the question less complex. I will add the note about unspecified container size though. Thank you.

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an idea that rely on scale. You keep the image in-flow (don't use `position:absolute`) then you scale the container by `0.9` which is 90% of the total height then you scale the image by `1.1` to keep it's original size. This will trim the image by 10% but since transform is only a visual effect you may have space at the top or the bottom of the container (based on the `transform-origin`)

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  outline:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
}

.container img {
  display:block;
}

.cut {
  transform:scaleY(0.9);
  transform-origin:top; /* The extra space will be on the bottom*/
}

.cut img {
  transform:scaleY(1.1);
  transform-origin:bottom; /* This should be bottom to cut the top*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="img" src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" >
</div>
<div class="container cut">
  <img class="img" src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" >
</div>
```

To be more precise we can consider `calc()` like below:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  outline:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
}

.container img {
  display:block;
}

.cut {
  transform:scaleY(0.9);
  transform-origin:top; /* The extra space will be on the bottom*/
}

.cut img {
  transform:scaleY(calc(1/0.9));
  transform-origin:bottom; /* This should be bottom to cut the top*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="img" src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" >
</div>
<div class="container cut">
  <img class="img" src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" >
</div>
```

Comment: Just as a note, the second `scaleY` should be `1.1111111...` since it's multiplying the `0.9` size. Though `1.1` will be fairly close.

Comment: @ShianiaWhite yes, it's more precesily 1/0.9 but wanted to make it simple ;) . I edited my answer to include an accurate method

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach to this without Javascript would be to translate the image up a certain percent, then scale it to fill the original height of the container. Anything else will leave a gap at the bottom.

```
.img_container img {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(2);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amoliski/n4ojdzyr/

Comment: The only issue with this method is that the resulting image is not the size it would have been otherwise. However, in my case, I can explicitly scale those other style values (i.e. `max-height` and `max-width`).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, using translateY (got that from [How can I get the height of an element using css only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153866/how-can-i-get-the-height-of-an-element-using-css-only))

As you can see, the .container does not have a hardcoded height, however, it will load with the original image height, which is 500px, even though the image is loading as 450px (500px - 10%)

```css
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.container img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="img" src="http://placekitten.com/400/500" />
</div>
```

Comment: The caveat is that there's a gap at the bottom of the container.

Comment: Yea, I think your answer is the most complete one :)

Comment: It's unfortunate that there is only `overflow-y` and no `overflow-bottom` otherwise a negative margin could solve the gap here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a little bit of JavaScript (I've inlined it for simplicity's sake but you could move it to it's own function)

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="img" src="http://placekitten.com/400/500" onload="javascript:this.parentElement.style.height = (this.height * 0.9)+'px';" />
</div>
```

Here's a working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uzahm6f5/).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use the `top` CSS property in a negative fashion on a relative image like the snippet below. This works for an image of an arbitary width and height. Just adjust your `top` value, accordingly.

```css
html,body{ height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    margin-bottom: -10%;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}

.container img {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    top: -10%;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="img" src="http://placekitten.com/400/500" />
</div>
```

To remove the extra bottom margin, just subtract the `margin-bottom` equal to the amount you subtracted from the top. Here it is `margin-bottom: -10%;`

Adjust the top value according to your dynamic images. Also note, I added `height:100%` to your container so you can see the full image but the top part is cropped. I used flex for centering. 
 Test for another image but this time, it is cropped `50%` from the top

```css
html,body{ height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -50%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}

.container img {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    top: -50%;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="img" src="https://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x_t3/sample_images/img/index/ff_x_t3_002.JPG" />
</div>
```

Comment: `top` will be relative to the height of its container, so you'll still need to set the containers height. Also, the amount that is cropped depends on the height of the container, which doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: @showdev yes and I'm sure by the question, the OP has a fixed height of the parent div and variable heights of images.

Comment: The OP says: "The height of the container should be unspecified (based on the image size)."