# CSS Crop image and set bounding box accordingly

Tags: css, image

I am trying to crop images in CSS but can't get it work as I wish. Here are three pictures to understand my problem :

The following screenshot represent what the "uncropped" elements look like.

[image: uncropped image]

For exemple, let's say I only want to keep the part of the first image going from 20% of its height to 60% of its height.

I tried to apply the following CSS to my red rectangle :

```
clip-path: polygon(0% 20%, 100% 20%, 100% 60%, 0% 60%);
```

And the result is

[image: badly cropped image]

Which is not good because there is still some blank space around the first image (the gray background was added for better visualization.)

The result I am trying to achieve is this

[image: nicely cropped image]

I got that by hardcoding values but this won't be possible.

Is this achievable with CSS only, and knowing the width and height of the original image ?

Comment: One idea is to [put the images in containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431572/cropping-the-top-10-of-an-image-using-css).

Comment: @showdev Good idea but this still leaves extra space unfortunately.

Comment: @showdev I edited my question because I don't think what I originally wanted is possible

Comment: If your images have a size you could add `object-fit: cover;` to them. This should make the images grow to fill the whole element

Comment: Using CSS aspect ratio on a surrounding div and positioning as a background image.

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth I'll go with your solution

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1:

using `object-fit, object-position` :

```css
.col {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 300px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <img style="object-position: 0 80%; height: 100px" src="https://source.unsplash.com/qap1hMjDA-g" />
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/22CdQfKG8uM" />
</div>
```

---

#### Solution 2:

using `background-size, background-position` :

```css
.col {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.img1 {
  background: url("https://source.unsplash.com/qap1hMjDA-g");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 70%;
  height: 100px;
}

.img2 {
  background: url("https://source.unsplash.com/22CdQfKG8uM");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="img1"></div>
  <div class="img2"></div>
</div>
```

> Note that you need to know the height of the images if you're using
> second solution